# Siddhi query for to calculate a new value using current event's value and last event's value

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

Whenever an event arrives there needs be a query to calculate a new value using current event's value and last event's value and insert it in to a new stream. 
For an example:

```
event [1]              : speed =  0 timestamp = 1410513924817    Calculated value(Acceleration) : 0
event [2]              : speed =  5 timestamp = 1410513924818    Calculated value(Acceleration) : ( 5 - 0)/1 = 5
event [3]              : speed = 10 timestamp = 1410513924819    Calculated value(Acceleration) : (10- 5)/1  = 5
event [4]              : speed = 13 timestamp = 1410513924820    Calculated value(Acceleration) : (13-10)/1  = 3
event [5]              : speed = 14 timestamp = 1410513924821    Calculated value(Acceleration) : (14-13)/1  = 1
event [6](current)     : speed = 15 timestamp = 1410513924822    Calculated value(Acceleration) : (15-14)/1  = 1
```

When using #window.lengthBatch(2) it allows to calculate the acceleration once for each two events. Does not fulfil the requirement. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a sequence,

E.g

```
from a=SpeedStream,b=SpeedStream
select b.speed-a.speed as acceleration, b.speed as currentSpeed
insert into AccelerationStream
```

Comment: speed values that we are referring to are in two different events in the same stream. Not in two different streams. I've read how to use sequences in wso2cep documentation, but couldn't see a way to solve above problem using it.

Comment: Here we are actually using the same stream in "from a=SpeedStream,b=SpeedStream" where event "a" will be immediately followed by event "b", if we are using different then it will look like "from a=SpeedStream1,b=SpeedStream2".